# First leg brought one day forward: compensation or change my flight?

Tags: cancellations, connecting-flights

I have a Milan-Paris-Boston (MXP-CDG-BOS) flight scheduled for late January. My flights were scheduled for the same day. However, my Milan-Paris (MXP-CDG) flight got cancelled and brought one day forward. Now I need to sleep in Paris CDG before catching my second flight.

I am undecided if changing my flight again and go back to my original plan with a 1h55m layover in Paris CDG (a bit short) or keep this flight, if I am allowed some kind of compensation.

My questions are: Am I allowed some kind of compensation since my flight got brought forward? If not, is 1h55m enough for a layover at CDG (I need to change terminal and go through security for the US)

**EDIT:** I did not get offered any compensation but I was wondering if I could ask for any. My first leg has been brought one day forward. The flights have been bought through the same company and yes they are connecting flights.

Comment: I do not know about the flight situation but as an extra option, if flights do not work out, there are (some) train travel options these days.

Comment: Which direction is "pushed back"? One day earlier than originally scheduled, or one day later?

Comment: Are the two flights on the same ticket, and were they scheduled to be connecting (I.e. without a stopover, just a few hours later by an airport rather than staying overnight)? The airline should contact you to to rearrange your second flight. They may be liable to pay for your hotel and meals though I haven’t checked if that applies in this case. But I don’t believe there could be any compensation due to the notification more than 2 weeks in advance.

Comment: I replied to all comments in an edit to my original question. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I understand it, if you accept what they've offered you then that's it, you don't get anything apart from that. To me this doesn't sound like a great offer, unless I particularly wanted to spend a night in Paris I would call the airline about changing my flight to something that works better for me.

Comment: Regarding whether 1h55 is enough, if an airline sells this as a connecting flight then they think it's pretty likely to be OK. If something does go wrong which causes you to miss your connection, the airline is responsible for sorting it out.

Comment: @Peter M I Googled and realized the mistake, thanks!

Comment: @PeterM Fixed in text too

Answer (score 5):

According to the official [EC261 page](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/indexamp_en.htm):

> If your flight is cancelled you have the right to choose between reimbursement, re-routing or return.
>
> You are also entitled to assistance at the airport.
>
> If you were informed of the cancellation less than 14 days prior to the scheduled departure date, you have a right to compensation.

So in your case you are not owed any compensation. You can ask for it (and if you are a frequent flyer with status or flying in a premium cabin you could possibly get a few miles/points), but there’s absolutely no obligation for the airline.

What often happens in such cases is that you receive an automated message informing you of the change of the flight directly affected, but it takes a bit longer for them to contact you about the rest of the trip (or in some cases nothing will happen until you contact them).

Your options are:

- to ask for a refund
- to have them change the other flight (or both flights) to have a better connection
- to keep the flights as they are and ask them to pay for the hotel and meals. Don’t go thinking you’ll be able to pick a nice hotel in central Paris and have them foot the bill though, they’ll send you to a hotel of their choice, most likely somewhere in CDG.

Flying MXP-CDG-BOS on a single ticket means you’re most likely flying Air France. This implies landing in 2F and departing from 2E (gates K, L or M). You’ll have to go through exit passport control, possibly security (though I’m not even sure). If your flight is on time, 1h55 is plenty of time for that. Even if your flight is up to one hour late it shouldn’t be an issue.

Beyond that it will become trickier, but as both flights are on the same ticket it is the airline’s responsibility you get to your destination timely, so:

- you would probably have staff waiting for you at the arrival gate to direct you to your departure gate, and possibly escort you through to make sure you don’t get lost or stuck somewhere
- they will probably hold the flight a bit if needed

If the incoming flight is very late and you can’t make the connection, they either have to reroute you (not sure there would be too many options) or arrange and pay for your hotel and meals. And since you would be delayed quite a bit, you would be due compensation in that case (unless extraordinary circumstances).